# Kubectl logs -f <pod> exit once the log print completes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I need to include kubectl logs -f  in a script, but since it's continuously running in my script it's not executing the next line of the script. Is there a way to exit the printing log once there are no more logs printing in the log file?

```
kubectl logs -f $POD $KUBECONF

while true;
  do
    kubectl exec $POD $KUBECONF --test -f /path/to/file
```

Comment: try to read last line of the logs for some fixed time period (e.g. 2 mins). if the lined didn't change within this time period, let script exit `while` loop and continue to the rest of the script

Comment: @rok the issue is since it's running before the while loop it's not reaching to the while loop

Comment: i suggest to wrap `kubectl logs -f $POD $KUBECONF` in a `while` loop ...

Comment: The "-f" flag in the command _kubectl logs -f $POD $KUBECONF_ specifies the logs to be streamed, removing it prints all the existing logs and exits the command. Is having the “ -f ” flag compulsory in your use case?